# How to root Micromax A089 Bolt without PC?

Tags: rooting

I have a Micromax A089 Bolt running Android Jelly Bean. I want to root it, but I do not have any PC. So how can I root it easily without PC?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You might wish to check our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). Questions like that are already covered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Framaroot](http://framaroot.net/) is a one-click universal root method that works on a number of Android devices. With a couple of root exploits attached with the app, you can easily root your device in no time. The app also allows users to unroot their devices within a single-click, so you can just go back to the unrooted state in a second should you want to. So without further ado, let’s see how you can root your device using Framaroot:

> **Before You Begin:**
>
> - This will void the warranty of your device. However, you can reinstate the warranty by unrooting your device if there’s any unrooting procedure available.
>
> **Downloading Required Files:**
>
> - Framaroot APK (It’s attached in the first post)
>
> **Rooting Your Android Device (Framaroot Method):**
>
> 1. Download the framaroot apk on you phone.
> 2. Head to `Menu>>Settings>>Security` on your device and enable the Unknown sources option.
> 3. Install the framaroot app.
> 4. Once the app’s been installed, launch it from your App Drawer.
> 5. Select Install SuperSU from the first dropdown menu.
> 6. As for selecting the exploit (there’re three, Sam, Frodo and Aragorn), head to this page and see what exploit works for your device. Once you find it out, tap on it in the app.
>    http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276
> 7. The app should begin rooting your device, shouldn’t take too long to finish.
> 8. Reboot your device once it’s been rooted.
> 9. You’re all done!
>
> Excellent! You’ve successfully rooted your Android device using the Framaroot app and you should now be able to see the SuperSU app in your App Drawer!

Source: http://www.theunlockr.com